# Why do I get the warning information "Modifier parameter should be named modifier" in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use  Jetpack Compose in a Android Studio project, the code A can work well, but I get the following warning information, why ?

*"Modifier parameter should be named modifier"*

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenAbout(
    rootModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {
    Scaffold(
        modifier = rootModifier.fillMaxSize(),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = { AboutAppBar(onBack = onBack) }
    ) { paddingValues ->

        Column(

   ...
}
```

Comment: There is a link check for the modifier parameter. It should be named "modifier".

Comment: Thanks! Why should I named it as  "modifier" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the code to [Lint Check](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/ui/ui-lint/src/main/java/androidx/compose/ui/lint/ModifierParameterDetector.kt).

It checks Composable functions with Modifiers parameters for consistency with guidelines.

For functions with one / more modifier parameters, the first modifier parameter must:

- **Be named `modifier`**
- Have a type of `Modifier`
- Either have no default value, or have a default value of `Modifier`
- If optional, be the first optional parameter in the parameter list

In you case just use:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenAbout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
```

Or if you want to suppress the warning add

```
@SuppressLint("ModifierParameter")
@Composable
fun ScreenAbout(
    rootModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
```

Comment: Any reason for this though? Like, why is it important that it be the first optional parameter, if optional? In the provided link there is a comment on line 140, saying `Hard to make a lint fix for this and keep parameter formatting, so ignore it`, but I'm not sure to what this refers to.

Comment: @Beko "[...] because a lot of developers pass a modifier after the required parameters (if any), otherwise they would be forced to use it as a named parameter." Source: https://blog.protein.tech/jetpack-compose-respect-the-contract-of-modifiers-ecbbe8ce03db